# Filter elements in list1 that are not in list2 java without using streams

Tags: java

Have two lists

```
     Class Fruit
     {
         private String name;
     }
     List<Fruit> list1 = new ArrayList<>;
     List<Fruit> list2 = new ArrayList<>;
```

Find elements in list1 that are not in list2 comparing by the field in Fruit - name.

Solution1:

```
     List list = new ArrayList<>;
     for(Fruit list : list1)
     {
          if(!list2.contains(list1)
          {
               list.add(list);
          }
     }
```

But this does not take into consideration the field - Name to compare. 
Please suggest the solution that helps in filtering with Name field without using streams

Comment: Are you having issue with this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not taking Fruit name in consideration because you didn't implemented `equals` method.

From [List boolean contains(Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : **o.equals(e)**).

in this last condition the one which will check based on your `equals` implementation.

You have to implement `equals` method in you Fruit class to compare based on `name`
 Eclipse generate equals method is below you can change based on your requirement:

```
public class Fruit {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Fruit other = (Fruit) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    } 

}
```

**UPDATE**
Anyway if you don't want to implement equals method you have to do bit more, here are stream code:

```
//It assume you have .getName() method in your Fruit class.
Predicate<Fruit> notInList2 = s -> list2.stream().noneMatch(e -> s.getName().equals(e.getName()));
List<Fruit> list3 =  list1.stream().filter(notInList2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can we use- 

           list1.forEach(listVal -> {
                    Fruit res = CollectionUtils.find(list2, new Predicate<Fruit>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean evaluate(Fruit o) {
                            return o.getName().equals(list1.getName());
                        }
                    });
                    if (res == null) {
                        list.add(listVal);

                    }
                });
Not sure how efficient this is compared to two for loops

Comment: @shreya updated the answer. Time complexity will remain same as we are checking each element in other list everytime.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a large amount of data, consider time complexity. In most cases, I will consider converting the list into a set and using the characteristics of the hash table to speed up the lookup.

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
 for(Fruit e:list2){
    set.add(e.name);
 }
 List<Fruit> result = new ArrayList<>();
 for(Fruit e:list1){
    if(!set.contains(e.name)){
        result.add(e);
    }
 }
```